# Can I treat this pointer in virtual function as this pointer of derived class

Tags: c++

```
class Base{
 public:
  virtual void show(){
      cout<<" In Base \n"; 
   }
};

class Derived: public Base 
{ 
    int x;
   public: 
       void show() {
             this->x = 10;
             this->printX(); 
         } 

        void printX(){
           cout<<x;
       }
}; 

int main(void) 
{ 
    Base *bp = new Derived; 
    bp->show();  // RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM 
    return 0; 
}
```

**My Question:**

```
         this->x = 10;
         this->printX();
```

since `this` is of type (`Base *`) can I treat it as (`Derived *`) and call/change `Derived` class specific members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since this is of type (Base *) can I treat it as (Derived *) and call/change Derived class specific members?

It is not a `Base*`. You are in the scope of `Derived::show`. In this scope its static type can only be a `Derived*`. Overriding `Base::show` or not doesn't affect that.

Accessing any member of `Derived` in `Derived::show` is therefore perfectly legitimate. This is how an overriding class is supposed to customize a behavior, by using its class specific members..